# How can I make sure that whaveter is in the text box is only 1's and 0's for binary?

Tags: javascript, function, loops, for-loop, alert

I have a app right now that converts binary to dec, hex and octal however I would like for it to alert the user if the input is not a binary number and tell them to try again. This is my code so far.

```
function isStringBinary() {

var x = document.getElementById('binary').value;

x = x.split('');

for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {

  if (x[i] !== 1 || x[i] !== 0) {

    alert('false');     

}}}
```

Any ideas? I would like to stick with the if and for loop though..

Comment: Why not add a regex pattern to the input element that refuses any character except a 0 or 1 (HTML5)?

Comment: You pasted some code and said "here's what I want to do" but you didn't describe the problem. Is something not working? If so, what is it doing vs. what do you expect it to do?

Answer (score 2):

Here's a simple binary validator using Regular Expressions, which is a simpler implementation, especially when you start adding octal and hexadecimal.

```js
var binary = document.getElementById("binary");
binary.addEventListener("input", function(e) {
  var validator = document.getElementById("validator");
  var text = e.target.value;
  if (text.match(/^[0|1]+$/))
    validator.innerHTML = "Valid Binary";
  else
    validator.innerHTML = "Not Valid Binary";
});
```

```html
<input id="binary" />
<span id="validator" />
```

Comment: Question: Why do you think a regex will have significantly better performance than a simple for() loop? I'd personally expect the regex to be slower, so I'm wondering if you have any data to substantiate that? I'm not saying this is a bad approach, I would just expect a regex to be slower than a simple loop.

Comment: @dman2306 perhaps I overstated the performance aspect. I removed that wording.

Answer (score 2):

NOTE!  ("1" == 1) will evaluate to true. 
("1" === 1) will evaluate false. 
You are comparing a string to an integer above so it will always fail.
(However, I would go with Dave's solution anyway).