# Input Validation for a String of Digits?

Tags: validation

I'm asking my user to enter digits between 0-1, and it could be at any length (1, 010, 100011110010, etc). I want to make sure the user does not enter any other digit (2, 1023, 567395), they must all be 0's or 1's.

I only know how to validate one digit answers, example:
while userinput != 0 and != 1:
      print("You must enter 0's or 1's.")

However since the number could be longer than one digit, that way doesn't work.

Can somebody show me how to do this please? And thankyou.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I make sure that whaveter is in the text box is only 1's and 0's for binary?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34189955/how-can-i-make-sure-that-whaveter-is-in-the-text-box-is-only-1s-and-0s-for-bin)

Comment: You can achieve this using regular expressions.  There are plenty of other questions discussing binary input validation.  What language are you using?

Comment: What language are you using?

Answer (score 0):

you said the solution literally I guess.
I'm going to use java coding.

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in); //scanner object  

while(scan.hasNextInt()) {    

int n = scan.nextInt();

    if (n != 0 && n != 1)   {  

         throw new IllegalArgumentException("You must enter 0's or 1's.");

    }

 }
```